# OOP python: Where to instantiate Cassandra and elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: python, oop, elasticsearch, cassandra, instantiation

I have an object which interact a lot with elasticsearch and cassandra. But I don't know where to instantiate my Cassandra and elasticsearch session. Should I put it in my "code", and pass the session into a parameters of my function like that:

```
cassandra_cluster = Cluster()
session = cassandra_cluster.connect()
es = Elasticsearch()

class Article:

    document_type = "cnn_article"

    def __init__(self):
        self.author = ""
        self.url = ""
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_crawl(cls, url):
        obj = cls()
        # Launch a crawler and fill the fields and return the object

    @classmethod
    def from_elasticseacrh(cls, elastic_search_document):
        obj = cls()
        # Read the response from elasticsearch and return the object

    def save_to_cassandra(self):
        # Save an object into cassandra
        session.execute(.....)

    def save_to_elasticsearch(self, index_name, es):
        # Save an object into elasticsearch
        es.index(index=index_name, ...)

    ...

article = Article.from_crawl("http://cnn.com/article/blabla")
article.save_to_cassandra(session)
article.save_to_elasticsearch("cnn", es)
```

Or should I put the instantiation of my cassandra and elasticsearch session as instance variables like that:

```
class Article:

    cassandra_cluster = Cluster()
    session = cassandra_cluster.connect()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    document_type = "cnn_article"

    def __init__(self):
        self.author = ""
        self.url = ""
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_crawl(cls, url):
        obj = cls()
        # Launch a crawler and fill the fields and return the object

    @classmethod
    def from_elasticseacrh(cls, elastic_search_document):
        obj = cls()
        # Read the response from elasticsearch and return the object

    def save_to_cassandra(self):
        # Save an object into cassandra
        session.execute(.....)

    def save_to_elasticsearch(self):
        # Save an object into elasticsearch
        es.index(....)

    ...

article = Article.from_crawl("http://cnn.com/article/blabla")
article.save_to_cassandra()
article.save_to_elasticsearch()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on their documentation and some of the examples here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-multiprocessing-example-for-improved-bulk-data-throughput

I would go with your second approach.  They mention that the session is only a context manager for shutting down connections, and their Query managers show them as being class attributes.

I think both would work, but if you want to multiprocess it, it may be marginally easier if you do it with the latter approach.